# How do I force ag (the silver searcher) to list empty files

Tags: search, ag

How do I get `ag` to list all files, including empty ones?

```
+ravi@boxy:~$ mkdir new && cd new
+ravi@boxy:~/new$ echo stuff > non-empty && touch empty
+ravi@boxy:~/new$ ag -ul
non-empty
+ravi@boxy:~/new$
```

How do I get `empty` to appear in the example above?

Comment: Just a guess but perhaps it's an optimization that says empty files can't match any text?

Comment: Why do you want to find empty files with `ag`?  The entire point of `ag` is to avoid searching files that have no chance to contain useful patterns.

Comment: They are files. Why break -l if a null pattern is supposed to match all files? ...Because it's faster and (and generally better) than 'find'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jeff [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303348/143394), the code didn't previously support this. I made a [Pull Request](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/pull/957) to fix the issue which has just now been merged in.

Note: The project maintainer is asking for help as his available time for `ag` is limited.

Comment: Too bad this forces one to include all the (in my case) garbage files with -u

Answer (score 3):

My suspicion is confirmed by looking at the [source](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/src/search.c) in the search_file function around line [258](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/src/search.c#L258), where it checks the file's size. If the size is zero, it bails out:

```
if (f_len == 0) {
    log_debug("Skipping %s: file is empty.", file_full_path);
    goto cleanup;
}
```

To confirm that this is the case, you may be able to use the [`--debug`](https://www.mankier.com/1/ag) option.

Comment: Yes, it comes up in the debug output. I've raised an issue at: [ag not printing empty files with -ul](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/956)